# PWM frequency for fan

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi, motor-controller, fan

I am building a small climate chamber, which is controlled by a Raspberry Pi Zero, electrical tubular heater, temp/rh sensors and an axial case fan.

This is the [fan](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/axial-fans/7980824/), which is connected to an [Adafruit TB6612 1.2A DC/Stepper Motor Driver Breakout Board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2448). I have an external 12V supply to the breakout board.

I have hooked up the fan to the TB6612 and RPi and its working nicely.

**Questions**

1. How do I determine the correct frequency setting for this fan?
2. I have tried a few settings and there is a noticeable and fairly loud clicking noise, which matches the frequency setting, why is there an audible noise?
3. Is there any way to prevent the audible noise from 2. above?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using a fan with PWM input? It would be both cheaper and easier.

Comment: How do you know if the fan can even be used with PWM, if the manufacturer datasheet does not specify if it can or cannot? You should ask the manufacturer if it is possible to use fan with PWM and what is the best frequency for PWM.

Comment: @winny The honest response is, I am a newbie and i didnt know at the time of ordering. So, now I have the bits, this is what I am trying to work with.

Comment: I see. Try to pick a very low frequency, say 100 Hz. You may still hear coil whining.

Comment: I wrote a loop that goes from 10 to 500hz and the noise is noticeable for all frequencies. It looks like the noise is unavoidable with my current setup.

Comment: Perhaps an LC filter on the output could help you somewhat. Or just a fan with PWM input (you can salvage one from almost any computer case made after 2000).

Comment: @winny thanks - i will see what I can find. Should the fan have 3 or 4 wires? Presumably three is +ve, -ve and PWM?

Comment: Correct. Four wire is +, -, PWM in and tacho out.

Comment: Three wire computer fans have only supply, ground, and tacho out - no PWM input, that's only on four wire fans.

Comment: @Justme I stand corrected.

Comment: So, the noise is unbearable and I have ordered an Arctic F12 PWM fan: https://www.arctic.de/media/d6/7d/b3/1583830370/spec_sheet_F12_PWM_180718_r7_EN.pdf I know to connect the 12v + and - to my 12v source. My next questions is do i need to connect the tacho out to anything? My final question is: can i send PWM signal direct from the Pi Zero or do this via the motor driver breakout board? The breakout board is wired in and working, so I can wire the PWM out from this fairly easily.